# How to disable incompatible type checks in CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am library linking my current project to a legacy C++ project which was compiling fine.

But when I try to use the same legacy project's API's in my current new project, it is throwing `error: asigning to uint32_t * (aka unsigned long *) from incompatible type unsigned int *` at the following line:

```
uint32_t *curval = static_cast<unsigned *>(storage_allocator_->ReserveUsingMalloc(getValSize());
```

I know that if I simply change `static_cast<unsigned *>`  to `static_cast<uint32_t *>`  in that legacy project, the above error would be resolved.

Unfortunately, for some genuine concerns, I am not allowed to modify that legacy project.

So, how do I disable this compilation check in my current CMakeLists.txt or any other options?

Comment: `unsigned int` is not necessary 32 bits, and it seems it changes according to your project. choosing target 32bits instead of 64bits might solve your issue.

Comment: While it's possible for `long` to be 32 bits wide, it's rather unusual for `uint32_t` to be based on `long`. Have the legacy project defined the `uint32_t` type themselves (with e.g. `typedef`)? And as a guess about the problem and how to solve it, perhaps the legacy project was developed for a 32-bit system where `long` was 32 bits, but now you're building on a 64-bit system where `long` is 64 bits wide? Perhaps you should ask the compiler to build in 32-bit mode?

Comment: yes, my current project is building for 64 bits

Comment: Assuming you use GCC, add the `-m32` flag when building and linking.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am compiling using Clang

Comment: IIRC it support that flag as well.

Comment: What compiler are you using? On all major ones on x86 32/64 bits platforms: `uint32_t` and `unsigned int` are matching types: https://godbolt.org/z/3v1PbY9T6

Answer (score 1):

Problem is not related with `cmake`. This is caused by invalid C++ code.
Error manifest when you are building to platform with specific bitness (32/64 bit), what is point out in comments.

This line is code smell:

```cpp
uint32_t *curval = static_cast<unsigned *>(storage_allocator_->ReserveUsingMalloc(getValSize()));
```

Why you are doing static_cast to one type and then you are doing assignment to other type? This should be consistent, so:

```cpp
uint32_t *curval = static_cast<uint32_t *>(storage_allocator_->ReserveUsingMalloc(getValSize()));
```

or

```cpp
unsigned *curval = static_cast<unsigned *>(storage_allocator_->ReserveUsingMalloc(getValSize()));
```

or use `auto`

```cpp
auto *curval = static_cast<uint32_t *>(storage_allocator_->ReserveUsingMalloc(getValSize()));
```

now proper solution depends on what type `storage_allocator_->ReserveUsingMalloc(getValSize())` returns  (you didn't provide that information).

Comment: I get your point, but as I said that this code smell is from a legacy project which I am not allowed to modify, but need to use few of its APIs. Hence the original question that how can I library link to that legacy module without getting a compilation error due to that check.

Comment: Just provide missing information (the more details you will provide then better) then we could help you to approach problem properly.

Comment: Just to be clear there is no flag to discard this error. You can only change architecture or fix this code.